# Preserving existing comments when parsing, modifying and dumping a YAML document

Tags: java, parser, yaml

Is there a library in a JVM language that allows me to parse an existing YAML document, accomplish a small modification in the file and dump it as another file such as existing comments are preserved?

Comment: No responses in 6 months. Do you insist specifically on a Java library, or will any tool that can do what you ask be useful?

Comment: In fact a library in any JVM language will do it (edited the question to reflect that). I would like this to be part of an existing tool-chain already written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it Jython runs on the JVM, with that you should be able to use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/)¹:

```
$ python
Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11) 
[OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_111
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ruamel.yaml
>>> yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
>>> data = yaml.load("""\
... a:
...   - elem1   # not very insteresting
...   - elem2   # more of the same
... b:
...   - 42
... c: {key: value}   # does it work?
... """)
>>> import sys
>>> yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
a:
- elem1     # not very insteresting
- elem2     # more of the same
b:
- 42
c: {key: value}   # does it work?
>>> exit()
$
```

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of that package.</sub>

Comment: Is there a self-contained Maven example?

Comment: I have no idea what Maven is, only heard about it by name. I am not sure it is appropriate here, but you could consider asking this as a full-fledged question to get some more people's notice.